# Extracting a specific column with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I'm trying to extract a specific column with beautifulsoup. The fourth in this link: https://livecapper.ru/bet365/event.php?id=4836898&t=1x2_ht and if the text in this column is: `-`
it will do some extra work with the second for loop. I tried this but it didn't work for me

```
for t in soup.find_all("td:nth-of-type(4)",text="-", limit=1):
  for g in soup.find_all("h1"):
    game_name.append(g.get_text()) if g.get_text() not in game_name else game_name
```

I also tried this to get the fourth column

```
for t in soup.find_all("td[4]",text="-", limit=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using css selector as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://livecapper.ru/bet365/event.php?id=4836898&t=1x2_ht'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

for tr in soup.select('.tablediv table tr td:nth-child(4)'):
    print(tr.text)
```

**Output:**

```
3.750
4.000
3.750
4.000
4.000
4.000
4.000
4.333
4.000
4.333
-
4.000
-
4.000
3.750
3.600
3.200
3.250
3.250
3.250
3.400
3.400
3.500
-
2.750
2.875
2.875
-
2.875
3.000
3.100
3.100
3.200
3.200
3.250
3.250
3.250
3.100
3.250
3.400
3.500
3.600
3.600
3.750
3.750
-
```